# Implemented BasicAuth, says its missing BasicAuth?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, basic-authentication

I've implemented... or rather copy pasted code from http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization/basic-authentication but when I try to run the website i get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'BasicAuth' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I'm working on the example so I have very little knowledge about what this is, why isn't it working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BasicAuth is the name of your application assembly, usually it is the name of your test application. You can check it in the project properties.